# Moving a site to a different site collection

Tags: 2007, development, migration, site-collection, site

I am looking for a C# script that will move a site with all permissions and content to another site collection. Google isn't helping me or maybe i dont know what exactly to look for.

e.g.

I have a site

usa3001.abcd.com\sites\mysite1
.
.
.
usa3001.abcd.com\sites\mysite103

I want to create a new site collections , it should move all everything e.g. content and  permissions

usa3001.abcd.com\mysite1
.
.
.
usa3001.abcd.com\mysite102

I know I can use stsadm to export it and import it but that gonna take too much time and effort for support time and they wont know whats happening.

Comment: Why do you need a C# script when this can be easily done through stsadm.

Comment: because i have hundreds of sites to be moved to new site collection

Comment: i updated my question :)

Comment: So write a script that calls STSADM commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single site (SPWeb) try using the content migration APIs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453426.aspx

```
SPExportObject exportObject = new SPExportObject();
```

and i've been successful with these settings:

```
            SPExportSettings settings = new SPExportSettings();
            settings.FileCompression = false;
            settings.ExportMethod = SPExportMethodType.ExportAll;
            settings.IncludeSecurity = SPIncludeSecurity.All;
            settings.IncludeVersions = SPIncludeVersions.All;
            settings.HaltOnWarning = false;
            settings.ExcludeDependencies = false;
```

For site collections you can do SPSiteCollection.Backup and SPSiteCollection.Restore:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsitecollection.backup

```
        SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup("http://url");
        SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApp.Sites;
        siteCollections.Backup(,,);
```

Comment: its a site with subwebs and subwebs..., and i give your answer a go now and then tell you if it works or not :), btw i tried stsadm and got error not sure if i will get same error here, here's the other question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/importing-a-site-to-a-new-site-collection-error

Answer (score 2):

Exporting a site should grab all the subsites as well.  I just did that this week by exporting an entire site collection and importing it as a subsite within an existing site collection.  Every subsite in the source site made it to the destination site.

I use:

```
stsadm -o export -url http://domain/sites/site -filename c:\temp\site.dat -nofilecompression -includeusersecurity -versions 4
```

and

```
stsadm -o import -url http://domain/sites/newsite/subsite -filename c:\temp\site.dat -nofilecompression -includeusersecurity
```

Comment: I tried that BEFORE but I am getting error, here is link for that question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/importing-a-site-to-a-new-site-collection-error

Comment: I don't think you want to use export/import for a site collection. You would use backup/restore for a site collection.

Comment: In this case, it was to export a site collection to import as a subsite in another site collection.  Backup and restore works if you need it to be a different top level collection but doesn't work properly if doing it as a subsite.

Comment: I have just a site with tens of subsites and more subsites in it, and I want to add this site to another site collection, I tried Import & export but I am getting error for that, and not sure if backup will get me everything, i tried to back up using central administration but i guess thats only for web applications and site collections in sharepoint 2007

Comment: First of all backup the site collection using stsadm -o backup and restore it to the new location /sites/mysitexyz and then use the content and strucutre to move the sites from sub-locations to top locations and then delete the parent webs.
You can also use SharePoint designer backup and restore subsites(not site collection) if they are small sites. I trust more to SP designer than import/export cmd as it works well for me compare to import/export.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

I found this article to be a good resource for me on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438819.aspx

*(Content Migration object model, the most flexible option)*