# importing a site to a new site collection error

Tags: 2007, development, migration, site-template, stsadm

I tried using STSADM to export / import a site definition, it exported properly, but when i tried to import it, it gave me fatal error that couldn't find a  webtemplate #id**** with LCID 1033, both sitecollections are on same server then why its asking for web template that is installed.

[Link to another of my question that might help you understand for what I am trying to do here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40912/moving-a-site-to-a-different-site-collection)

**Exact error**

> FatalError: Could not find WebTemplate #10016 with LCID 1033.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.VerifyWebTemplat
>   e(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.Validate(SPRequi
>   rementObject reqObj)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.DeserializeAndVa
>   lidate()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.VerifyRequirements()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
>   Progress: Import Completed.
>   Finish Time: 7/13/2012 12:34:34 PM.
>   Completed with 0 warnings.
>   Completed with 1 errors.

I have 4 Site Collections atm

/
/a
/b
/c/d

I just created "d" as a new site collection dunno why it went into c tho, anyway

Source =     /a/a.1/a.2

destination  =  /c/a.2

that's what I wanted but gave me above error while importing

Comment: Do you mean a site collection instead of a site definition?

Comment: Can you post the EXACT error?  Thanks.

Comment: Is the destination in the same WebApplication? If not: are the same features/solutions deployed to the destination WebApp?

Comment: its the same web app, I created a new site collections from central admin, So I guess its using same web APP. I added more information

Comment: STSADM [export](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262759.aspx) is for subsites. STSADM [backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441.aspx) is for site collections.

Comment: Give a try to SP designer.

Comment: already did, it but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with site collection so had to create a new one from scratch.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)